# How to add send array in the SQL query and calculate SUM using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sql-server

I have an array in variable `$id = Array([0] => 5 , [1]=> 6)`. Now I want to pass the value to the SQL query and calculate the SUM, but somehow it's not calculating the SUM rather then its displaying output 100500 which should be 600 (like: 100+500 = 600).

My PHP code is :

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
for($i = 0; $i<count($id); $i++) {
$sql = getAmount($id[$i]);
}

function getAmount(&$id){
global $mysqli;
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT SUM(amount) AS total FROM work WHERE id = (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($amount);
    $stmt->fetch();
echo $amount['total'];
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not summing the sql result;

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$sum = 0;
for($i = 0; $i<count($id); $i++) {
$sum = $sum + getAmount($id[$i]);
}
echo $sum;//Print the summing result

function getAmount(&$id){
global $mysqli;
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT SUM(amount) AS total FROM work WHERE id = (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($amount);
    $stmt->fetch();
return $amount['total'];
 }
```

You should return query sum result from `getAmount` function and you should sum the returning results in the loop. After completed the loop, you can print the sum result.

Comment: I was going to answer this. Good solution!

Answer (score -1):

column `amount` must be some of integer or float types: int, bigint, tinyint, longint, float, double